# Occasional crash in destructor when cleaning up owned (!) string member

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, lldb

I am trying to track down a bug that occasionally crashes my app in the destructor of this trivial C++ class:

```
class CrashClass {

public:
         CrashClass(double r1, double s1, double r2, double s2, double r3, double s3, string dateTime) : mR1(r1), mS1(s1), mR2(r2), mS2(s2), mR3(r3), mS3(s3), mDateTime(dateTime) { }
         CrashClass() : mR1(0), mS1(0), mR2(0), mS2(0), mR3(0), mS3(0) { }
        ~CrashClass() {}

    string  GetDateTime()   { return mDateTime; }

private:
    double mR1, mS1, mR2, mS2, mR3, mS3;
    string mDateTime;
};
```

A bunch of those objects is stuck in a standard C++ `vector` and used in a second class:

```
class MyClass {
    (...)

private:
    vector<CrashClass>    mCrashClassVec;
};
```

`MyClass` is created and dealloc'd as required many times over.

The code is using C++17 on the latest Xcode 10.1 under macOS 10.14.4.

All of this is part of a computationally intensive simulation app running for multiple hours to days. On a 6-core i7 machine running 12 calculations in parallel (using macOS' GCD framework) this frequently crashes after a couple of hours with a

**pointer being freed was not allocated**

error when invoking `mCrashClassVec.clear()` on the member in `MyClass`, i.e.

```
frame #0: 0x00007fff769a72f6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
frame #1: 0x00000001004aa80d libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 284
frame #2: 0x00007fff769116a6 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
frame #3: 0x00007fff76a1f977 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_vreport + 545
frame #4: 0x00007fff76a1f738 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_report + 151
frame #5: 0x0000000100069448 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] std::__1::__libcpp_deallocate(__ptr=<unavailable>) at new:236 [opt]
frame #6: 0x0000000100069443 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] std::__1::allocator<char>::deallocate(__p=<unavailable>) at memory:1796 [opt]
frame #7: 0x0000000100069443 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<char> >::deallocate(__p=<unavailable>) at memory:1555 [opt]
frame #8: 0x0000000100069443 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() at string:1941 [opt]
frame #9: 0x0000000100069439 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() at string:1936 [opt]
frame #10: 0x0000000100069439 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] CrashClass::~CrashClass(this=<unavailable>) at CrashClass.h:61 [opt]
frame #11: 0x0000000100069439 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] CrashClass::~CrashClass(this=<unavailable>) at CrashClass.h:61 [opt]
frame #12: 0x0000000100069439 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] std::__1::allocator<CrashClass>::destroy(this=<unavailable>, __p=<unavailable>) at memory:1860 [opt]
frame #13: 0x0000000100069439 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] void std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<CrashClass> >::__destroy<CrashClass>(__a=<unavailable>, __p=<unavailable>) at memory:1727 [opt]
frame #14: 0x0000000100069439 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] void std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<CrashClass> >::destroy<CrashClass>(__a=<unavailable>, __p=<unavailable>) at memory:1595 [opt]
frame #15: 0x0000000100069439 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] std::__1::__vector_base<CrashClass, std::__1::allocator<CrashClass> >::__destruct_at_end(this=<unavailable>, __new_last=0x00000001011ad000) at vector:413 [opt]
frame #16: 0x0000000100069429 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] std::__1::__vector_base<CrashClass, std::__1::allocator<CrashClass> >::clear(this=<unavailable>) at vector:356 [opt]
frame #17: 0x0000000100069422 BackTester`MyClass::DoStuff(int, int) [inlined] std::__1::vector<CrashClass, std::__1::allocator<CrashClass> >::clear(this=<unavailable>) at vector:749 [opt]
```

*Side note:* The `vector` being cleared might have no elements (yet).

In the stacktrace (`bt all`) I can see other threads performing operations on their copies of `CrashClass` vectors but as far as I can see from comparing addresses in the stack trace all of those are in fact private copies (as designed), i.e. none of this data is shared between the threads.

**Naturally** the bug only occurs in full production mode, i.e. all attempts to reproduce the crash

- running in **DEBUG** mode,
- running under Lldb's (Xcode's) **Address Sanitizer** (for *many* hours/overnight),
- running under Lldb's (Xcode's) **Thread Sanitizer**  (for *many* hours/overnight),
- running a cut-down version of the class with just the critical code left/replicated,

failed and did **not** trigger the crash.

Why might **deallocating a simple member allocated on the stack** fail with a *pointer being freed was not allocated* error?

Also additional hints on how to debug this or trigger the bug in a more robust to investigate further are very much welcome.

**Update 5/2019**

The bug is still around intermittently crashing the app and I'm starting to believe that the issues I'm experiencing are actually caused by Intel's data corruption bug in recent CPU models..

https://mjtsai.com/blog/2019/05/17/microarchitectural-data-sampling-mds-mitigation/

https://mjtsai.com/blog/2017/06/27/bug-in-skylake-and-kaby-lake-hyper-threading/

https://www.tomshardware.com/news/hyperthreading-kaby-lake-skylake-skylake-x,34876.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187405/discussion-on-question-by-atv-occasional-crash-in-destructor-when-cleaning-up-ow).

Comment: I doubt it's a CPU bug. More likely you smashed some stack or heap somewhere. The fact that you only get the bug in production and not when you remove a bunch of code, points to UB in the removed code. Audit it.

Answer (score 2):

You might try a few tricks:

- Run the production version using a single thread for an even longer duration (say a week or 2) to see if it crashes.
- Ensure that you don't consume all available RAM taking into account the fact that you might have memory fragmentation.
- Ensure that your program does not have memory leak or increase memory usage the more long it runs.
- Add some tracking by adding extra value, set value to something known in destructor (so you would recognize the pattern if you do a double delete).
- Try to run the program under another platform and compiler.
- Your compiler or library might contains bugs. Try another (more recent) version.
- Remove code from the original version until it crashes no more. That works better if you can consistently get the crash with a sequence that somehow corrupt memory.
- Once you got a crash, run the program with the exact same data (for each thread) and see if it always crash at the same location.
- Rewrite or validate any unsafe code in your application. Avoid casting, printf and other old school variable argument function and any unsafe strcpy and similar function.
- Use checked STL version.
- Try unoptimized release version.
- Try optimized debug version.
- Learn the differences between DEBUG and RELEASE version for your compiler.
- Rewrite problematic code from zero. Maybe it won't have the bug.
- Inspect the data when it crashes.
- Review your error/exception handling to see if you ignore some potential problem.
- Test how you program behave when it run out of memory, out of disk space, when an exception is thrown…
- Ensure that your debugger stop at each thrown exception handled or not.
- Ensure that your program compile and run without warnings or that you understand them and are sure it does not matters.
- Inspect the data when it crash to see if look good.
- You might reserve memory to reduce fragmentation and reallocation. If your program runs for hours, it might be possible that the memory get too much fragmented and the system cannot find a block that is big enough.
- Since your program is multithreaded, ensure that your run-time is also compatible with that.
- Ensure that you don't share data across thread or that they are adequately protected.

Comment: Many thanks, couple of things I haven't tried yet. Will report!